# No such table on HTC desire HD (SQLite database on Android)

Tags: android, sqlite

Please take a look at the following function :

```
 private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);


        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        File f = new File(DB_PATH);
        if (!f.exists()) {
        f.mkdir();
        }

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        //myInput.read(buffer);
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }
```

Where DB_PATH is  "/data/data/*application package*/databases/". Is it possible to set DB_PATH="" ? Actually setting DB_PATH = "/data/data/*application package*/databases/". works fine on most devices, but does not work on HTC desire HD ( discussed [here](http://www.anddev.org/networking-database-problems-f29/missing-table-in-sqlite-with-specific-version-of-desire-hd-t50364.html) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889516/sqlite-exception-on-android-device-no-such-table-but-emulator-works-fine) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662941/missing-table-in-sqlite-with-specific-version-of-htc-desire-hd) and [here](http://www.anddev.org/networking-database-problems-f29/missing-table-in-sqlite-with-specific-version-of-desire-hd-t50364.html) ). This device does not find the mentioned path on the device. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should set your `DB_PATH` like this:

```
String DB_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getAbsolutePath()
```

That will give you the full path to your Database.. then you can use that as your `outFileName`.